# How to force evaluation of a statement in my `init` file?

Tags: elisp, helm

TL;DR: How can I force evaluation of a `setq` statement at start-up so that `imenu` updates appropriately?  (You can skip down to the second code-block below, if you want.)

I love the concept of `imenu` (esp. when integrated with `helm`) and I think it has great potential to improve my workflow...assuming I learn how to correctly set definitions for `imenu` categories.

As a simplified example, let's say that I'd like to add a few definitions to my `init` file's `imenu` which would be useful when making updates - namely, the list of imported packages.

Let's consider the following three lines as the code we want to parse (purely illustrative; my `init` file doesn't actually have an explicit line for importing `dired` and `electric`):

```
(defconst dc/default-directory "/path/to/directory")
(use-package dired)
(use-package electric)
```

In order to extract the constants and package names in `imenu`, I've included the code below in my `init.el` file.  This code works BUT only after I manually `eval` the second line, (i.e., the second `setq` statement below).

```
(setq dc-additions '(("Imported packages" ".*(use-package \\(.*\\))*" 1)
                     ("Defined constants" ".*(defconst \\(.*\\))*"    1)))
(setq imenu-generic-expression (copy-sequence `(,@dc-additions ,@imenu-generic-expression)))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode 'imenu-generic-expression)
```

If I don't manually evaluate the second step, the `imenu` list shows only the default definitions.  However, after I `eval` the second statement above, the `imenu` list correctly include includes items based on my definition.

How can I force evaluation of the second statement?  In other words, what can I do to to ensure that `imenu` will automatically consider items based on my definition?

---

Exhibit 1: `imenu` after start-up but before I manually `eval` the second `setq` statement:

[image]

Exhibit 2: `imenu` after I manually `eval` the statement:

[image]

Comment: Could you try `helm-imenu` alone? `helm-semantic-or-imenu`, as its name suggests, use either semantic **or** imenu. If the command has candidates from `helm-semantic`, it won't display imenu's candidates, unless the candidates from `helm-semantic` is `nil`. There's also a stand alone `helm-semantic`. The advantage of `helm-semantic` is that it provides more information, so you can look thing like function interface and preselect the candidate when run `helm-semantic`. But Imenu is easier to extend without touching Semantic parser.

Comment: unfortunately, `helm-imenu` is also blank.  in fact, both `helm-imenu` and `helm-semantic` are blank.

Comment: You use `setq` which overrides the default `imenu-generic-expression`, and I think your regex is potentially wrong, so it shows nothing. Try removing your change and test `helm-imenu` again.

Comment: @Tu Do: I've updated the methodology so that my new list of definitions is appended to the existing list (using the `,@` operator).  As described in my (heavily) edited post above, the new code works but only after I manually evaluated part of the code (details above).

Comment: You're saying it doesn't take effect during initialization?

Comment: @Malabarba That's right, I've added before and after pictures for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`imenu-generic-expression` is a buffer local variable. When opening a new buffer, imenu will set imenu-generic-expression local value to something interesting for the current buffer. So setting imenu-generic-expression in init won't be useful, as its default-value is never used.

What you want to set is the variable that it used by imenu for setting imenu-generic-expression in `emacs-lisp-mode`. It seem that it is the value from `lisp-imenu-generic-expression`, that is define in `lisp-mode`. So you just have to:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
    (setq lisp-imenu-generic-expression (append dc-additions lisp-imenu-generic-expression)))
```

Note that you must eval the `setq lisp-imenu-generic-expression` in a `with-eval-after-load` because you depend on the default value of `lisp-imenu-generic-expression` that won't be known to Emacs before lisp-mode is loaded.